# Swift fileExistsAtPath always returns false

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my code i'm trying to get the path with `getFilePath` and after that i check if the file exists.

The file exists, but it returns false.

Here is my code:

```
let myPath = getFilePath()

let fileExists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(myPath as String)
```

myPath is a NSString and this is what it returns on debug

```
myPath  NSString    "/Users/ricardoalves/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1B8360B0-F6CD-4A53-B33D-698091E2D506/data/Containers/Data/Application/985AB3BD-89BC-45FF-AC26-97DD24B304FA/Documents/data.plist"   0x7aea8cd0
```

Comment: 1. What's your definition of `getFilePath()`? 2. What value returns `false` where you are *certain* that it should not?

Comment: I get the path file that is supose, but when it checks of the file exists, then it return false

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without seeing either one. You also have a cast to String there. Why is that needed? What's datatype is `myPath`

Comment: If you print `myPath as String`, what does it show?

Comment: If `getFilePath` returns a non-optional String, you shouldn't need to do `myPath as String`. You really should show the code of what `getFilePath` is doing.